# Event loop for Twitter4r

Tags: ruby, twitter, twitter-gem

Is there an event loop for Twitter4R where when a user mentions the bot's handle, it will notify the bot?

I have tried to make it work with checking `client.mentions_timeline` every 5 seconds to see if there are new tweets that are mentioning the bot's handle. It worked, however, the rate limit often time gets exceeded after checking `client.mentions_timeline` numerous times. Is there a way that I can optimize this or am I missing something?

```sh
         6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/users.rb:237:in `user'
         5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/users.rb:53:in `verify_credentials'
         4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:57:in `perform_get_with_object'
         3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:72:in `perform_request_with_object'
         2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:50:in `perform_request'
         1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/request.rb:39:in `perform'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/rest/request.rb:81:in `fail_or_return_response_body': Rate limit exceeded (Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The gem is just a wrapper for the API so refer to the [Rate Limits](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits) on Twitter where we find this:

> GET endpoints The standard API rate limits described in this table
>   refer to GET (read) endpoints. Note that endpoints not listed in the
>   chart default to 15 requests per allotted user. All request windows
>   are 15 minutes in length.  These rate limits apply to the standard API
>   endpoints only, does not apply to premium APIs.

```
GET statuses/mentions_timeline  statuses    75  0
```

So it looks like you can only hit that endpoint 75 times per 15 minutes and the simple math for that is

```
15 * 60 / 75 = 12
```

So you probably should not hit it more than once every 12-15 seconds to be safe.

You could also keep track of your calls over time, rescue the exception and retry the request in the event that you hit the rate limit.